# Pygame Not Responding! despite calling event and updating screen

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

It works perfectly if I do not add it in a class, but if I do it does not respond, I have tried using *pygame.update*, as *pygame.event.pump/get* and even jumbling were event should start from, still the problem persists. What am I doing wrong?Code below

```
.
.
class start_game:
    def __init__(self,path,width = 400,height = 600):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.head  = None
        self.running = False
        self.path   = path
        
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()
        
        self.background = load_img(self.path + '\AnimatedStreet.png')
        self.enemy = pygame.image.load(self.path + '\Enemy.png')
        self.backg0_pos =  [0,0] 
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width,self.height))
         
    
    def _run(self):
        self.running = True
        
        while self.running:
            #pygame.event.pump()
            self.screen.fill([0,0,0])
            self.screen.blit(self.background, self.backg0_pos)
            
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.display.update()
            
            self.backg0_pos[1] += 1
   
            self._init_controls()
            
            return
    
    def _init_controls(self):
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    self.player_pos[0] += 5

                if event.key == K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
             
        return
    
a = start_game(path)
a._run()
```

Comment: Your while loop ends after the first loop because you put “return” inside the loop. That’s the problem. Also, you should use flip() or update(), not both.

Comment: You do a `return` in the application loop

Comment: @Starbuck5 Thank you , that sorted it, how did could I miss that!

Answer (score 0):

The error was the return function put inside of the while loop caused it stop.
The solution was putting the return function inside of the run function.